# Accessing setting throws exception after publish to server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I setup settings in a web project's properties, for example AccessToken.  In my code I access the setting by using

```
string accessToken = Settings.Default.AccessToken;
```

When I debug locally, it works just fine.  When I deploy to a test server using Web Publish (VS2015), it deploys fine.  Looking at the web.config, I see the setting is set properly.

When the code runs, it throws an exception, that value of the property 'serializeAs' cannot be parsed.  I added code just before accessing the property to check what is being read:

```
foreach (SettingsProperty property in Settings.Default.Properties)
{
   Log.InfoFormat("Property: {0}   SerializeAs: {1}   Value: {2}", property.Name, property.SerializeAs, property.DefaultValue);
}
```

From the logging, I see the name of the property is correct, and SerializeAs is a String, and the value looks good. I can't figure out what could be causing this.  Anyone have ideas?

As a side note: I had to recreate my publish settings just before this. They somehow were deleted. When I publish, I get 'Publish: 1 succeeded' and nothing looks out of the ordinary in the build/publish output.  When I access it this way, I get the value.

```
string accessToken = Settings.Default.Properties["AccessToken"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work.  When web publishing, I tried deploying a different configuration (release).  In Configuration Manager, I had the typical Debug and Release configurations, but I also had a Production and Test configuration.  The release config worked in the Test environment.  Looking at the Test configuration, I noticed that one project was not set to use the same config as the others.  Changing the config for the project in Configuration Manager fixed my problem.  Something must have got out of sync, and this fixed it.  Just strange that the web.config was correct, but that accessing the property caused an exception.  So, it's fixed now, time to move on.